# ASP --> ASP.Net: Refactoring steps

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I have a legacy ASP application which - at some point soon - needs to be migrated to ASP.Net 2.0 (to be compatible with other apps that are also in 2.0).

Are there best practices for this sort of thing i.e. is it possible/advisable as a first step to transfer the current unholy mix of html, vbscript and javascript en masse to aspx pages (without any code-behind separation), and then iteratively replace vbscript with data sources and the like, or this more trouble than its worth?

[The app is not *that* complex (we are talking 10 or so .asp pages, with a similar number of .inc files), but the mix of html and scripts is not at all pretty: lots of if-else statements to build SQL commands etc.].

Comment: Can you go to ASP.NET 3.5/4 with MVC? It would be a much simpler port?

Comment: unfortunately not - we have two apps: an asp one and an asp.net 2.0 one, and there are no plans to upgrade from 2.0 to a higher version of asp.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vbscript might look similar to VB.NET but there's a difference. Besides the CreateObject calls need to be replaced by calls to objects in .NET land.

I suggest that you take out the html parts and put those already in your pages, same goes for javascript, images and css (those can mostly be taken in total without much change (sometimes none at all) to your new application.

This article might also be of interest to you: [Converting ASP to ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973813.aspx).